# AJAX Throbber - Keep throbber image but delete Please wait... message?

Tags: forms, ajax

This question has been asked a few times in various forms but is there a simple way to keep the animated blue throbbing image but delete the Please wait... text?

I'm trying this in my form_alter hook:

```
unset($form['my-model']['#ajax']['progress']['message']);
// or
$form['my-model']['#ajax']['progress']['message'] = '';
```

But this appears to remove the message AND the animated throbber! I want the throbber to remain. Is it a requirement for message to not be empty for the throbber to even render?

Comment: I'd make sure that `$form['my-model']['#ajax']['progress']['type'] = 'throbber';` and `$form['my-model']['#ajax']['progress']['message'] = NULL;`

Comment: @Jimajamma That's a no go. The throbber.gif still does not appear if the message is set to NULL. The type defaults to 'throbber' by default so I do not need to verify that.

Comment: @Jimajamma Never mind! That did indeed work. After I explicitly set the type to throbber and message to NULL I got exactly what I wanted. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

@Jimajamma answered the question correctly in the first comment.

```
 $form['my-model']['#ajax']['progress']['type'] = 'throbber';
 $form['my-model']['#ajax']['progress']['message'] = NULL;
```

Must explicitly be set and configured within the ['#ajax'] form element.